# I can't add a Header to a specific multipart part in golang

Tags: http, go

I'm using an API that requires the content-type of a multipart form to be Content-Type: audio/wav but if you add a file with
`part, _ := writer.CreateFormFile("audio_file", "test2.wav")`
it makes the content-type application/octet-stream

I've tried:
`part.Header.Set("Content-Type", "audio/wav")`
but Header is undefined.

Here is the curl request data minus the binary that works:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio_file"; filename="test2.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav
```

Here is my request minus the binary data that is rejected:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio_file"; filename="test2.wav"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [CreatePart](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Writer.CreatePart) directly instead of the CreateFormFile convenience method.  Set the content type in the header used to create the part.

```
h := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
h.Set("Content-Disposition",
    fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"`, "audio_file", "test2.wav"))
h.Set("Content-Type", "audio/wav")
part, err := writer.CreatePart(h)
```